# Green lettuce water?

Tags: lettuce

Typically I chop up a head of romaine, swish it around in some cool water, then spin it dry.  The swishing water ends up very green, however.  I'm wondering if it's getting doused in some dye prior to purchase, or if I'm preparing it wrong and leeching out the nutrients?

Comment: It doesn't turn very green when I do that. Just slightly, which is to be expected, from chlorophyll leaching out of the cut cells.

Comment: When you say chop, what size do you chop? If it's caused by the number of cut cells, the smaller you chop, the greener the water...

Comment: @Juilio that would explain why it varies so much from head to head (since I chop larger for salads, smaller for tacos).  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I never heard of lettuce dye, I wouldn't panic with that. You are not loosing nutriments either, like Michael said it might be chlorophyll, wich would explain the green color, but you are not losing nutriments for sure. I often have green water too, it's really not a big deal, don't worry!

Comment: So maybe that lettuce water will be good for the plants.  ;)

Comment: My homegrown lettuce does the same thing, and it's definitely not dyed. And yes, the lettuce water is excellent for plants. I keep a dish pan in the sink all summer to catch gray water to put on the garden, since we never get enough rain. N.B. I do not water plants I intend to eat with this gray water, just to be safe. But I have lots of flowers & ornamentals.